# How to make my test pass a non mult-dimensional array to my React Test?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jestjs

I have a utility method that I am writing a test for and I am trying to pass arguments to accurately portray usage and produce a non multi-dimensional array. Here is my code

```js
const arrayInsert = (arr: any[], index: number, ...newItems) => [
    ...arr.slice(0, index),
    ...newItems,
    ...arr.slice(index)
];

export default arrayInsert;
```

As you see the last argument is a `spread` operator. And right now I am passing arguments to my test that produce a multi-dimensional array instead of adding to the array like this example:

```js
arrayInsert(["A", "B", "F"], 1, "C", "D", "E");

// produces
["A", "C", "D", "E", "B", "F"]
```

So I want my test to be written to accurately portray the above example.

```js
import arrayInsert from "./arrayInsert";

describe("arrayInsert", () => {
    it("should return array containing an array of new items", () => {
        const arr = ["A", "B", "F"];
        const newItems = ["C", "D", "E"];
        const index = 1;
        const expected = ["A", ["C", "D", "E"], "B", "F"];

        expect(arrayInsert(arr, index, newItems)).toEqual(expected);
    });
});
```

How can I make the result one dimensional?